# Regular expression to remove hostname and port from URL?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to write some javascript to strip the hostname:port part from a url, meaning I want to extract the path part only.

i.e. I want to write a function getPath(url) such that getPath("http://host:8081/path/to/something") returns "/path/to/something"

Can this be done using regular expressions?

Comment: This doesn't require regular expressions at all - see my answer :)

Comment: It's not that it doesn't require regular expressions.  This shouldn't be done using regular expressions.

Comment: But it's still useful to know.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Quick 'n' dirty:

```
^[^#]*?://.*?(/.*)$
```

Everything after the hostname and port (including the initial /) is captured in the first group.

Comment: Or in regular expression literal form ("/" needs to be escaped): /^.*?:\/\/.*?(\/.*)$/.exec("http://example.com/folder/file.ext")[1] gives "/folder/file.ext"

Comment: This regex is wrong.  It captures the path, query and fragment in group 1.

Comment: Regex isn't necessary at all! Nice though!

Comment: @mikesamuel, The question asked to remove the hostname and port.  I'll correct my answer to have a suitable explanation, though.

Comment: @strager, Doesn't this still convert some URLs that have no scheme or authority portions into ones that do.  For example `#foo://bar//example.com/` has no scheme or authority but your regex will change it into a protocol relative URL that has an authority `//example.com/`.

Comment: @Mike Samuel, That is very true.  As I said, it's quick and dirty, and by no means a robust solution.  You can work around the issue by using `[^#]*?` instead of `.*?` for the protocol.  I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 29):

RFC 3986 ( http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt ) says in Appendix B

The following line is the regular expression for breaking-down a
   well-formed URI reference into its components.

```
  ^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
   12            3  4          5       6  7        8 9
```

The numbers in the second line above are only to assist readability;
   they indicate the reference points for each subexpression (i.e., each
   paired parenthesis).  We refer to the value matched for subexpression
    as $.  For example, matching the above expression to

```
  http://www.ics.uci.edu/pub/ietf/uri/#Related
```

results in the following subexpression matches:

```
  $1 = http:
  $2 = http
  $3 = //www.ics.uci.edu
  $4 = www.ics.uci.edu
  $5 = /pub/ietf/uri/
  $6 = <undefined>
  $7 = <undefined>
  $8 = #Related
  $9 = Related
```

where `<undefined>` indicates that the component is not present, as is
   the case for the query component in the above example.  Therefore, we
   can determine the value of the five components as

```
  scheme    = $2
  authority = $4
  path      = $5
  query     = $7
  fragment  = $9
```

Comment: The regex is mistakenly surrounded with ** and **.

Comment: A thorough reply and one I found useful—though not as direct as the accepted answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

I know regular expressions are useful but they're not necessary in this situation. The Location object is inherent of all links within the DOM and has a pathname property.

So, to access that property of some random URL you could need to create a new DOM element and then return its pathname.

An example, which will ALWAYS work perfectly:

```
function getPath(url) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    return a.pathname.substr(0,1) === '/' ? a.pathname : '/' + a.pathname;
}
```

jQuery version: (uses regex to add leading slash if needed)

```
function getPath(url) {
    return $('<a/>').attr('href',url)[0].pathname.replace(/^[^\/]/,'/');
}
```

Comment: I know it's an old post, but I really like your method J-P :)

Comment: Note that this will ONLY work if you have a DOM. In environments like node.js or web workers, there is no DOM. (Probably not a common condition in 2009 when this answer was written...)

Answer (score 4):

The window.location object has pathname, search and hash properties which contain what you require.

for this page

```
location.pathname = '/questions/441755/regular-expression-to-remove-hostname-and-port-from-url'  
location.search = '' //because there is no query string
location.hash = ''
```

so you could use

```
var fullpath = location.pathname+location.search+location.hash
```

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple:

```
^\w+:.*?(:)\d*
```

Trying to find second occurance of ":" followed by number and preceded by http or https.

This works for below two cases

Ex:

http://localhost:8080/myapplication

https://localhost:8080/myapplication

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression seems to work: **(http://[^/]*)(/.*)**

As a test I ran this search and replace in a text editor:

```
 Search: (http://[^/]*)(/.*)
Replace: Part #1: \1\nPart #2: \2
```

It converted this this text:

```
http://host:8081/path/to/something
```

into this:

```
Part #1: http://host:8081
Part #2: /path/to/something
```

and converted this:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441755/regular-expression-to-remove-hostname-and-port-from-url
```

into this:

```
Part #1: http://stackoverflow.com
Part #2: /questions/441755/regular-expression-to-remove-hostname-and-port-from-url
```