# Regex help - stripping out the domain name

Tags: regex

Say my URL is

- `https://foo.bar.com/somedirectory/somefile.php` or
- `http://abc.bar.co.uk/somedirectory/somefile.php`

What would the regex be to get

- `/somedirectory/somefile.php` or
- `somedirectory/somefile.php`?

Comment: Which language are you using? It's likely that the language provides a function to parse URIs.

Comment: Search for "regex url" here in SO. There's probably over a dozen such questions with accepted answers. On a side note... you should probably use some method given by your language of choice to parse an url.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression to remove hostname and port from URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441755/regular-expression-to-remove-hostname-and-port-from-url)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your URL always starts with either `http://` or `https://`, this should work (and since you didn't specify a language, here's an implementation in Perl):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @urls=("https://foo.bar.com/somedirectory/somefile.php", "http://abc.bar.co.uk/somedirectory/somefile.php");

foreach my $url(@urls)
{
  if($url=~/^http(?:s)?:\/\/[^\/]+(\/.*)$/)
  {
    print "$1\n";
  }
  else
  {
    print "$url did not match!\n";
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
/somedirectory/somefile.php
/somedirectory/somefile.php
```

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

Using javascript (you can test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6Z3R9/)):

To return "/somedirectory/somefile.php":

```
var inputString = "https://foo.bar.com/somedirectory/somefile.php";
var regex = /https?:[\/]{2}\S*?(\/\S*)/;
var outputString = inputString.replace(regex,"$1");
alert(outputString);​
```

To return "somedirectory/somefile.php", change the regex like this:

```
var regex = /https?:[\/]{2}\S*?\/(\S*)/;
```

**RegEx**

The core regex is as follows. This may need to be tweaked a bit based on which language you are using:

```
https?:[\/]{2}\S*?(\/\S*)
```

To extend this for ftp sites, you could use

```
(ht|f)tps?:[\/]{2}\S*?(\/\S*)
```