# Regular expression for getting pathname of a url

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to extract the complete path i.e the path followed by the host name of a URL in javascript.

```
var url = 'https://domain.us/file.php/fghfgh?id=1'
```

Here i want to extract  `/file.php/fghfgh?id=1`

How can this achieve only using regular expression not by "`document.createElement('a')`"   methode ?

I need the answer in regular expression ,

Comment: Does the url always end with .us ?? Maybe you could just simply use the string.split(".us") --- This returns an array where array[1] holds the url part you want.

Comment: what is the "document.createElement('a')" method?, I have never heard of it before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to remove hostname and port from URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441755/regular-expression-to-remove-hostname-and-port-from-url)

Comment: the above one is just an example .I want to extract the string (include pathname + searchname) after the hostname of any url  .Need answer in regular expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are accessing the [location object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location), you could do

`var path = location.href.replace(location.protocol+"//"+location.hostname,"")`

or

`var path = location.pathname+location.search`

If you have # you may need to add it too as pointed out by just_mad:

`var path = location.pathname+location.search+location.hash`

Answer (score 2):

```
^[^#]*?://.*?(/.*)$
```

Credit goes to strager:

[Regular expression to remove hostname and port from URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441755/regular-expression-to-remove-hostname-and-port-from-url)

Answer (score 1):

How about using something tried and true: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/parseuri

There's even a demo: http://stevenlevithan.com/demo/parseuri/js/

Answer (score 1):

and here is a much more specific regex for your question;

```
https?://[-A-Z0-9.]+(/[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;?]*)?
```

Comment: i've checked with a regex tester and it worked. can you be more specific about the problem?

Comment: i don't know regular expression very well . I tested like this way                                                              var url = 'http://www.suntimes.com/csp/cms/sites/STM/assets/js/jquery-latest.js'
  var path = url.match(/https?://[-A-Z0-9.]+(/[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;?]*)?/);
alert(path)

Comment: but i couldn't get path as  /csp/cms/sites/STM/assets/js/jquery-latest.js