# Get path and query string from URL using javascript

Tags: javascript, url, uri

I have this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/found-locations/?state=--&km=km
```

I want this:

```
found-locations/?state=--&km=km
```

how do i do this in javascript?

I tried `window.location.href` but it is giving me whole url
I tried `window.location.pathname.substr(1)` but it is giving me `found-locations/`

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441755/regular-expression-to-remove-hostname-and-port-from-url

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Use `location.pathname` and `location.search`:

```
(location.pathname+location.search).substr(1)
```

Comment: What is the browser support for this, I found: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/search

Comment: What is `.substr(1)` for?

Comment: @AmitTripathi the `.substr(1)` is to remove the slash at the start

Answer (score 59):

```
window.location.pathname + window.location.search
```

Will get you the base url `/found-locations` plus the query string `?state=--&km=km`

Answer (score 17):

If your url is a string, you can create `URL` object and use `pathname` and `search` property.

```
 let strurl = 'http://www.test.com/param1/param2?test=abc';
 let url = new URL(strurl)
 let pathandQuery = url.pathname + url.search;
```

```js
let strurl = 'http://www.test.com/param1/param2?test=abc';
let url = new URL(strurl)
let pathandQuery = url.pathname + url.search;

console.log(pathandQuery);
```

Comment: [Not supported by IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL)

Answer (score 7):

get all path, query and even hash: `location.href.replace(location.origin, '')`

Answer (score 4):

[URI.js](http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/) is a nice JavaScript library for parsing URIs. It can do what you requested with a nice fluent syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @returns The path and query string (and possibly the hash fragment) of the current URL.
 */
export const getRelativeUrl = (url: string): string => {
  const urlObject = new URL(url);

  return `${urlObject.pathname}${urlObject.search}${urlObject.hash}`;
};
```

The cleanest version for getting relative URL.