# JavaScript: how to redirect from "example.com/page1" to "example.com/page2" in same domain?

Tags: javascript

I want a JavaScript code that redirects `https://www.example.com/collections/all?sort_by=best-selling` to `https://www.example.com/collections/all` in the same domain name using JavaScript.

Comment: "I want".. well, then write some code. It's not that difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it would redirect to `/collections/all` of the current domain:

```
   if (location.href.includes('/collections/all?sort_by=best-selling ') 
       window.location.replace("/collections/all");
```

Comment: Hi @iliya.rudberg, this will redirect any page I visited to `/collections/all`, but I want the visitor to redirect to `/collections/all` only if he's visiting `/collections/all?sort_by=best-selling`

Answer (score 0):

you can also use

```
window.location.assign
```

Check out the difference between window.location.assign and window.location.replace answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4505846/4987870

Comment: Hi @Sandeep Shukla, this will redirect any page I visited to `/collections/all`, but I want the visitor to redirect to `/collections/all` only if he's visiting this specific page: `/collections/all?sort_by=best-selling`

Comment: The whole idea here is I want to not make spayers spy on my store and see the best seller products

Comment: Checking the path is quite easy check this answer `
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376438/get-path-and-query-string-from-url-using-javascript`

Answer (score 0):

If you use `window.location.assign("yoururl")` it causes a new document to load. If you use `window.location.replace("yoururl")` it replaces the current doc and replaces the current History with that URL making it so you can't go back to the previous document loaded.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Location/assign
Ref : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Location/replace